# How can I tell which libraries are added when Skype installs?

Tags: c#, chromium

So we're trying to deploy Chromium with an application. We're including all of the required files to the client machines but noticed that the application fails unless Skype is installed. Installing Skype fixes the problem. Is there any way I can tell what changes Skype is making other than installing it's core application?

The error that's thrown sans-Skype is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>   File name: 'CefSharp.Core.dll'
>     at CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor(String address)
>     at EncompassToChrome.ChromeControl..ctor(String URL)
>     at fb7f2542af19424d4f995c0e6750158283.__fb7f2542af19424d4f995c0e6750158283_Form1_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs EventArgs)
>     at EllieMae.Encompass.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>     at EllieMae.Encompass.Forms.Form.InvokeLoad()
>     at EllieMae.EMLite.InputEngine.InputHandlerBase.executeLoadEvent()

Comment: To find the dependendant dlls of a managed assembly like cefsharpcore.dll, open it in ilspy. To find unmanaged dependencies, use dependencywalker.

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)

Comment: Thanks, dependencywalker in combination with SysInternals Process Monitor mentioned below helped me figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without going to deep:

The error message says: CefSharp.Core.dll is missing.
Have a look for this file.

For detailed debugging you can use SysInternals 'Process Monitor'.

This tool can log all file access during the installation or tried file access when run the application.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I was looking for. I'll try that now.

Comment: CefSharp.Core.dll is where it should be though, which leads me to believe it's got a shared dependency with Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. A combo of Mr Makielski's recommendation to use SysInternals 'Process Monitor' and HugoRune's to use dependencywalker was the answer for me.

Used Process Monitor to find the files created when skype installs and cross referenced those against the unmanaged dependency list dependencywalker gave me. turned out to be: msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll that I needed.